# Finding values for which the function is non negative

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus

I feel like it's an easy one but I'm having hard time to prove it, how can I show that :

For every $0<a<2$ there exists an $0<x \leq 1$ such that $(1-x)(2a-x)-a^2 \geq 0$

Will appreciate any clues. Thanks

Comment: For any $a$, this is a continuous function in $x$. The intermediate value theorem applies. Show that at $x = 0$, the inequality is true, and thus there is a neighborhood around $x = 0$ where the inequality is true.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Very elegant, thank you David !